# Ubuntu Installing mdadm

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, raid, mdadm

I need to use RAID to my nvidia jetson tx2 server machine.
I started from webmin for make RAID configuration
I gor this error;

```
The kernel RAID status file /proc/mdstat does not exist on your system. Your kernel probably does not support RAID.
```

After, I tried install mdadm to my ubuntu server machihe and I got this error;

[image]

What can I do?

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS NVIDIA jetson tx2

Kernel 4.9.125-tegra

Comment: Where did that kernel come from?

Comment: I do not make any installation for kernel. I used uname -r command for show kernel version and I got this. @David

Comment: That's an Nvidia-specific version of Ubuntu, which is not supported here. [From the docs](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/linux-tegra): "NVIDIA® Jetson™ Linux Driver Package (L4T) is the board support package for Jetson. It includes Linux Kernel 4.9, bootloader, NVIDIA drivers, flashing utilities, sample filesystem based on Ubuntu 18.04, and more for the Jetson platform." You will need to ask your question [on the Nvidia Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/agx-autonomous-machines/jetson-embedded-systems/70) 